# Stuck on Intro to linux lab Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: command-line

I am currently in an intro to Linux class. We are using Ubuntu 10.04 and I am stuck on a lab problem. Here are the instructions:

> Create a script called get_dirs that lists the directories in a directory, trims off any extra characters, and stores the data in a file called current_dirs. Run the script and verify the output. Make an alias for this command called gd. Check that the alias works then logout and log back in. Check to see if the alias is still valid

It is an online class and my instructor is currently unavailable. Up until this point in class I've been doing well but I can't figure out how to complete the directions in the first sentence.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. We're not a script writing service. This is a class, presumably you've already been given the information needed to do this (hint: look at the commands `ls` and `find`). _Try_ something and feel free to post back here if you have a specific problem. We're happy to _help_ you with your homework but we won't do it for you.

Comment: Where are you stuck with? Or are we suggesting that we develop the script?

Comment: What have you done so far?  Please post your attempt so far as well as the output.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably look for directories in the current working directory with something like `find -maxdepth 1 -type d`. This introduces some issues in that in adds `./` to the paths... Here's a demo:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d
.
./sites
./stories
./templates
./media
```

I think that's what your instructions means by "extra characters". That's what it wants you to clean up so whatever you end up writing, from the above example, you'd end up with:

```
sites
stories
templates
media
```

For cleaning you'd want to look at tools like `sed`, `grep` and `awk` (any of those could do it and you should only need one)... You could even look at `find`'s `-exec` or `-fprint` clauses but that's pretty advanced IMO.

I think the rest is fairly self explanatory. Create a command that gets clean versions of the directory names, which saves its output in a file (see: bash redirection), check that it's right and then create a persistent bash alias for it.

I say "create a command" above because I see no value in creating a standalone bash script for such a silly little command, especially if you're creating an alias later on... But your instructor might be expecting a standalone script *and* an alias. Might not hurt to go the extra mile.